# LPCSTR- How to check if first Position is a Space " "

Tags: c++, char, compare, lpcstr

Simple Question.

How to check what char is on first Position on a LPCSTR?

Or just check if there is a Space on first Position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an LPCSTR named `str`, you can access the first character using `str[0]`.  For example:

```
if (str[0] == ' ') {
    // First character is a space
}
```

Comment: @JensKrüger Yes, `*a` and `a[0]` are equivalent expressions (when not considering operator overloading).